# Find a sequence $\{z_n\}$ s.t. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|z_n|=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(z_n)=1001$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to ask you for help on a problem:

Let $f$ be an entire function that is not a polynomial. a) Show there exists a sequence $(z_n)$ such that $|z_n|\to \infty$ and $f(z_n) \to 1001.$ b) Give an explicit example of such an $f.$

My intuition:
$f$ is holomorphic on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ and the series expansion of $f(z)$ is infinite and $f$ is not bounded.

Beside proving the existence, how could one find such an example?

Comment: Can you freely choose $z_n$ and $f$? If yes, what's wrong with $z_n = n$ and $f(n) = 1001 + 1/n$?

Comment: you can simplify and generalize the search searching for $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c$ for any chosen $c\in\Bbb C$ and $x\in\Bbb R$. You can also transform this limit in terms of complex numbers $x$ if you want. By example setting $f(x):=c\tanh x$ or $f(z):=c\tanh |z|$.

Comment: Please put "Suppose $f$ ..." at the beginning, for obvious reasons.

Comment: This problem makes no sense as stated. What are you assuming? What is this $f$ that you're asking questions about?

Comment: @zhw actually the problem can be split into two different ones: 1) Find explicitely the sequence $\{z_n\}$ with the limit conditions above; 2) Suppose $f$ is entire and is not a polynomial, prove that there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}$ such that the limit conditions above are satified.

Comment: @FunnyBuzer I've edited the problem to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Since $f$ is not a polynomial, $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n,$ with $a_n\ne 0$ for infinitely many $n.$ The function $f(1/z)$ then has an essential singularity at $0.$ It follows from Casorati-Weierstrass that there is a sequence $a_n \to 0$ such that $f(1/a_n) \to 1001.$ Since $|1/a_n| \to \infty,$ we're done.

b) Let $f(z) = e^z$ and take $z_n = \ln 1001 +i(2\pi n), n= 1,2,\dots $

---

**Previous answer** Hint: Your $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty.$ Apply Casorati-Weierstrass.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: By Weierstrass-Casorati theorem, for any $c\in\mathbb{C}\cap\{\infty\}$, there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}$, $z_n \rightarrow a$ s.t. $\lim_{n\rightarrow n}f(z_n)=c$, if $f$ has an isolated singularity at $a$. I don't see, though, why in my case I have an isolated singularity at a.

Comment: @FunnyBuzer  You are assuming $f$ is entire and $f$ is not a polynomial, right?

Comment: @FunnyBuzer Perhaps you missed it when I said "essential singularity at $\infty$" I expanded my hint to a more complete answer.

Comment: now I see it! Thanks